# Angular test Type Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chai, karma-mocha

Have tried a test case in karma, Mocha chai and sinon.

Am getting a error once I use the service. This is my error. Please any help.

```
AssertionError: expected undefined to deeply equal 'strong'
        at /var/www/html/Testing/mocha/node_modules/chai/chai.js:210
        at assertEql (/var/www/html/Testing/mocha/node_modules/chai/chai.js:784)
        at /var/www/html/Testing/mocha/node_modules/chai/chai.js:3854
        at /var/www/html/Testing/mocha/www/index-controller.test.js:22
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.043 secs / 0.002 secs)
```

This is my `indexcontroller.js`

```
'use strict';

angular.module('beatso.index-controller', [])
    .controller('IndexController', function(
        commanService) {
        (function(vm){
            angular.extend(vm, {
                checkPassword: checkPassword
            })

            vm.headingTop = "Beatso A Music Fanatic Group";
            vm.password = "verystrogpassword";
            function checkPassword() {
                return commanService.passwordValidator("vm.password");
            }
        })(this);
    });
```

This is my test for indexcontroller.
indeccontroller.test.js

```
describe('Index Controller', function() {
    var indexController;
    var commanServiceMock;
    var commanService;

    beforeEach(module('beatso.index-controller'));
    beforeEach(module(initMocks));
    beforeEach(inject(initIndexController));

    it('should return strong if password length is greater than equal to 8', function() {

        expect(indexController.checkPassword()).to.eql('strong');            
        expect(commanServiceMock.passwordValidator.calledOnce).to.eql(true);

    });


    function initMocks ($provide){


        commanServiceMock = {
            passwordValidator: sinon.spy()
        };
        $provide.service('commanService', function(){
            return commanServiceMock;
        })
    }

    function initIndexController($controller) {
        indexController = $controller('IndexController');
    }
});
```

This is my common service

```
  'use strict';

    angular.module('beatso-comman.service', [])
        .factory('commanService', function(){
            var service = {
                passwordValidator: passwordValidator
            }

            function passwordValidator(password){
                if(password.length >= 8) {
                    return 'strong'
                }else {
                    return 'weak'
                }
            }
            return service;
        })
```

Here is my test for the service.

```
 'use strict'

    describe('Test for my comman service', function(){

        var cService;

        beforeEach(module('beatso-comman.service'));
        beforeEach(inject(initCommanService));

        it('It should check the password strength', function(){
            expect(cService.passwordValidator('amtoverystrongpassword')).to.eql('strong');
        });

        function initCommanService(commanService){
            cService = commanService;
        }
    })
```

Comment: Btw, remove quotes in `passwordValidator("vm.password")`, as you want to check the *value* of `vm.password`.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelP.Bazos But my problem is not solved yet. Can you please help me.

Comment: I'm aware this is not the cause of the `'undefined' is not a function`. Your main problem is that you want to test a service method with a mocked service, that has no method.

Comment: Have done that. But still having an error.

Comment: AssertionError: expected undefined to deeply equal 'strong' This is the error

Comment: Can you add the test of the service at the end of the question?

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos Have added my test for the service.

Answer (score 1):

Your commanService mock has no method "passwordValidator", so trying to call it raise an "undefined" error.

If you do want to test your service, you should not mock it but actually really test it. You can get a reference to your service by injecting it (see inject() function in Jasmine).

Here's a piece of code from one of my project:

```
// inject the service itself 
beforeEach(inject(function(nfcService){
    service = nfcService;
}));
```

Where, obviously, "service" is the variable I am using to perform my unit tests (and really test my service).

Edit - details:
What I mean above is, the tests of your controller should not test your service... The tests of your controller should test your controller. It should, eventually, using a mock of your service (with a spy on the desired method), check that the appropriate method has been called.

For instance:

```
myServiceMock = {
    expectedMethod: jasmine.createSpy('expectedMethod spy')
}
```

And in your test:

```
expect(myServiceMock.expectedMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

When instantiating a controller with `$controller`, you can pass it (in a second parameter) an object literal providing its dependencies. This way, you can give it the mock you want.

An example, still from my project:

```
    menuCtrl = $controller('MenuController', {
        // where 'uiFeedbackService' is the name of the dependency
        'uiFeedbackService': uiFeedbackServiceMock
    });
```

---

*Note: Regarding the declaration of your service, you can directly `return` an Object literal instead of creating a variable, declaring a private function (passwordValidator), and then returning the variable.*

```
angular.module('beatso-comman.service', [])
.factory('commanService', function(){
    return {
        passwordValidator: function(password){
            if(password.length >= 8) {
                return 'strong'
            }else {
                return 'weak'
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, Have updated my code. can you please check it.

Comment: Hi. This time you're having "undefined" because your indexController is not having the desired method (checkPassword). How did you come to use inject() this way? (Calling another function, `initIndexController` ??)